# Getting string from jquery mobile multiselect to put in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get the values from my select list on a jquery mobile app.

Here is my select markup:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="stuff" class="select">Stuff:</label>
                <select name="stuff" id="stuff" multiple="multiple">
                    <option value=''>Select One</option>
                    <option value="Stuff 1">Stuff 1</option>
                    <option value="Stuff 2">Stuff 2</option>
                    <option value="Stuff 3">Stuff 3</option>
                    <option value="Stuff 4">Stuff 4</option>
                    <option value="Stuff 5">Stuff 5</option>
                    <option value="Stuff 6">Stuff 6</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

How do I get the comma separated string of values from this multiselect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use jquery `val()` method to retreive array of selected values and `join` method to combine them:

```
var commaSeparatedValues = $("#stuff").val().join(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple use jquery `val` method:

```
var vals = $('#stuff').val();  // Array, e.g. ["Stuff 2", "Stuff 3"]
console.log(vals.join(','));   // String 'Stuff 2,Stuff 3'
```

Comment: console.log outputs result to browser's console if it is defined. Most of modern browsers contains javascript consoles.

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/logging. `Console` is your friend. It's built-in in Chrome and Safary as well.